# get biginteger value from FileOutputStream

Tags: java

```
 public void writed()
    {
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\key01.txt"); 
            fos.write(d.toByteArray());
            System.out.println("Done");

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("\nError in writed: " + e.getMessage());}
    }

privateKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey)keypair.getPrivate();
p = privateKey.getPrimeP();
q = privateKey.getPrimeQ();
phiN = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
e = privateKey.getPublicExponent();
d = e.modInverse(phiN);
```

Any idea how to read the d from key01.txt? or better way to read and write the data from txt file?

Comment: Do you want the d? You will have to read a bit more about Java IO. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: where is d coming from? Sorry I don't see it defined/initialized anywhere. Is d the name of a package?

Comment: You can just google: http://www.google.com/search?q=java+read+and+write+the+data+from+txt+file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a small off topic remark: it is confusing to give a file with binary contant a `.txt` extension.

To read the value back: read the file contents into a byte array and then call the `BigInteger(byte[] val)` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("foo.txt");
try {
    String everything = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
} finally {
        inputStream.close();
}
```

Or look at this question:
[Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)

Comment: The file in this question is not a text file, it contains binary content.